# Public properties usage when inherited from private class

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

I have three classes which have many common properties, so I generated a base class from which they inherit:

```
public class CommonConfig
{
   public TimeSpan Period1 { get; private set; }
   public TimeSpan Period2 { get; private set; }
   public TimeSpan Period3 { get; private set; }
};

public class Config1 : CommonConfig
{
   public long count1 {get; private set; }
}

public class Config2 : CommonConfig
{
   public long count2 {get; private set; }
}
```

I am not sure that I want to make `CommonConfig` to be `public`. Is it possible to keep it `private` but still make something that allows usage like below.

```
Config1 c1;
TimeSpan ts1 = c1.Period1;
```

Comment: You can't change the accessibility of a class hierarchy. Think about it, if the base class is private or internal and the derived class public, how would client code access the base class? The answer is that it cannot.

Comment: NO. you can't. You have to keep `CommonConfig` as `public`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not, as to be able to access to the property of that class, you need to specify it `public`, and you can not specify `private` a class which properties are `public` .

```
Config1 c1;
TimeSpan  ts1 = c1.Period1; // THIS PROPERTY HS TO BE PUBLIC
```

and if you

```
//MISMATCH BETWEEN CLASS AND ITS PROPERTIES ACCESS MODIFIERS
private class CommonConfig {
    public TimeSpan Period1 { get; private set; }
    public TimeSpan Period2 { get; private set; }
    public TimeSpan Period3 { get; private set; }

}
```

and even more, you will get compiler error:

> Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as
>   private, protected, or protected internal

As defining a class on the "top" level (on level of the namespace) you have to declare it `public`. If you want to hide it, you have to declare that class *inside another class*.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a class `private`, `internal` is the most restrictive possible modifier for a non nested class.

Also you cannot have the access for descendant classes less restrictive than the parent class, so you have to stick with `public` for `CommonConfig`.

Comment: Unless it's a class nested within another class

Comment: @SamLeach true, i modified my answer

Answer (score 1):

No You can not make it as private.
you can not access private class with public property.
you must specify Public class

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to prevent usage of the class `CommonConfig` directly, you could mark the class `CommonConfig` as `abstract` and also the properties within it (as required).
That way, though the class would be visible but the only way to use it would be via `Config1` or `Config2` .

[See this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6118/All-about-abstract-classes) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
public class CommonConfig
{
    public TimeSpan Period1 {get; protected set;}
{
```

You could also make the whole attribute protected if needed...